# Copy-Paste data of one polygon to another, LEAFLET

Tags: leaflet, qgis

I have a Polygon Layer in Leaflet. Each polygon have an unique ID.
Is there any possibility to copy data from one polygon to another*except ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
var poly1 = L.polygon(latlngs, options);
var copyPoly = L.polgygon(poly1.getLatLngs(),poly1.options);
// copyPoly.options.uiqueId = newId; // when the Id is stored in the options
```

If this is not working, share your code with us